# Query Count Monthly of this year - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-query-builder

Today is *9/25/2019*

I'm trying to query my visitor with in this year of 2019 only.

Then, I want to know how many are on

**1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9**

## I've tried

```
$raw = Visitor::query()
->whereYear('created_at', now()->year -1)
->get()
->pluck('created_at');

$data = [];
foreach ($raw as $i=>$date) {
    $data[$i] = Carbon::parse($date)->format('m');
    if(  Carbon::parse($date)->format('m')[0] != 0 ){
        $data[$i] = Carbon::parse($date)->format('m');
    }else{
        $data[$i] = str_replace('0','',Carbon::parse($date)->format('m'));
    }
}

// dd($data);

$dataValues = array_count_values($data);

dd($dataValues);
```

I got

```
array:5 [▼
  8 => 314
  9 => 916
  10 => 764
  11 => 827
  12 => 765
]
```

Why would I get anything in the future since this month is only September (9) ?

How can I correct it?

I was hoping to get something like this

```
array:9 [▼
      0 => 314
      1 => 916
      2 => 764
      3 => 827
      4 => 165
      5 => 225
      6 => 565
      7 => 65
      8 => 1265

    ]
```

I would like to get an array-like above output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should extract month from date then groubby ,and don't forgot select count :

```
    Visitor::whereYear('created_at', Carbon::now()->year)
->select(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at) month"),DB::raw("count('month') as vistors_count"))
       ->groupby('month')
       ->get();
```

Comment: I think you are **very** close. Can you show array of count only -  instead array of of laravel objects.

Comment: Can we leverage ->pluck() ?

Comment: can you share the  return result ?

Comment: How do I update your query so I don't have to do a for each loop ?

Comment: i would to see the result of query

Comment: maybe using  ->get()->keyBy('month') to listed by month

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you might try.

Laravel automatically makes `created_at` into a Carbon object, so if you create your query like this:

```
$raw = Visitor
      ::whereYear('created_at', \Carbon::now()->year) <<-- Note 2019, not -1 for 2018
      ->select('created_at')
      ->get();
```

Here you get an object with the Carbon date field, `created_at`.  You then won't need to use `parse` in your if-checks.

I suspect perhaps the answer to your question, though, is that it looks like you are pulling items from 2018, when you want 2019.  You have subtracted a year off of this year in your original query.

Comment: Let me try your suggestion now. I hope it is working. I will update you how it goes.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  This is a collection of Visitor objects from the year 2019 with the `created_at` field supplied.  You can put that $raw into your foreach and loop on the each visitor model and pull the created date.  `foreach ($raw as $visitor) { $month= $visitor->created_at->month }`  And then you can do your counts on them per month like you did originally.  Count by result or loop or whichever is easiest for you.